# Using marks in terminal/Terminator for easier navigation

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminator

Sometimes I find it difficult to scroll through the console output in a terminal window for reaching a specific command's output.

I have just found out super cool feature which is embedded in the OS'x Terminal,written here:

[How to Use Marks in OS X’s Terminal for Easier Navigation](https://www.howtogeek.com/256548/how-to-use-marks-in-os-xs-terminal-for-easier-navigation/)

I'm looking for the same feature in Linux terminal such as Terminator, have somebody stumble upon a feature like this on Linux??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of any terminal emulator with this feature under Linux. Here's the feature request for VTE (gnome-terminal, terminator etc.): https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767230.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll follow this feature request :)

Comment: I'm looking for the same, here in the Apple help page is described: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/terminal/trml135fbc26/mac

I'ts really a good utility, I don't know how can't be done in any linux terminal-app